# Can I create virtual machine without virtual network in Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create virtual machine (VM) in Azure using ARM templates. In classical model of IAAS, we can create a virtual machine without virtual network in cloud service. Similar to classical model i don't want to put VM in virtual network.

Does anyone tried to create vm without virtual network in Azure resource manager.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

V2Vms, i.e. Resource manager VMs have a dependency on a network card, which has a dependency on a subnet.

A VNet is used to provide DHCP and Security Group services to the VM. Without it a VM couldn't obtain an IP Address.

It is not possible to create an Azure VM without a vnet, in the same way that it was not possible to create a V1Vm without a cloud service.

For more information see [Understanding Resource Manager deployment and classic deployment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-manager-deployment-model/)

Comment: What are V2Vm and V1Vm here?